# DecimalFormat pattern of ##0.0E0 returning 1.235E3

Tags: java, decimalformat

DecimalFormat appears to be ignoring the pattern for the decimal part of a number.

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
formatter.applyPattern("##0.0E");
String text = formatter.format(Double.valueOf(1234.5678));
// text is 1.235E3
```

Why doesn't it return 1.2E3?

Comment: Reading the DecimalFormat javadoc section on scientific notation I suspect it is related to the minimum and maximum number of integer digits and how they impact the output? I've not had a chance to look more deeply though.

Comment: When I read the doc it says that the number of significant digits in the mantissa is the minimum integer digits (1) plus the maximum fraction digits (1) so it should be at least 2 (1.23E3) but I can't conclude from the documentation why it becomes 3 digits.

Comment: You are forcing it into engineering notation. See the Javadoc.

Comment: @user207421 Is there a way to take it out of engineering notation? I'm trying to emulate what Excel does.

Answer (score 0):

`0.#E0` would give you the correct answer.